# asp.net (VB) strange double image upload with CodeFile and no Namespace

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

All.
(Using CodeFile for pages published to a webserver
Removing Namespace, as I get errors after adding CodeFile)

I created a video for everyone to see the issue live. This is creating a new web project and then demonstrating the issue.
[Please click here to view the video](https://www.cffcs.com/stuff/Demo2.mp4).

I've run into a strange issue that I'm hoping someone will be able to assist with.
Below are identical codes, with only the CodeBehind and CodeFile, and the namespace removal changed.

The issue is this.
The below code will upload a single image that is renamed with the date.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="ImageServer.Test" %>
```

This code will upload duplicates of the image renamed with a date.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %>
```

If you upload the file with its default name, it will only upload ONE file, regardless of the Inherits property.
So, this will upload single files either way.

```
Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)
 postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & fileName)
```

This code will upload duplicates with CodeFile and no Namespace.

```
Dim getYear As String = (((((now.ToString("hh") & "") + now.ToString("mm") & "") + now.ToString("ss") & "") + now.ToString("mm") & "") + now.ToString("dd") & "") + now.ToString("yyyy") + now.ToString("fff") + ""
Dim testName As String = getYear + ext
postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & testName)
```

Any idea what is going on here?
Text.aspx (Uncomment each Page header to test out code)

```
<%'@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="ImageServer.Test" %> <!--Singles-->
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test"%> <!--Duplicates-->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=fuUpload]").change(function () {
            if (typeof (FileReader) !="undefined") {
                var dvPreview = $("#dvPreview");
                dvPreview.html("");
                var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
                $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                    var file = $(this);
                    if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                        var reader =new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            var img = $("<img />");
                            img.attr("style","height:100px;width: 100px");
                            img.attr("src", e.target.result);
                            dvPreview.append(img);
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                    }else {
                        alert(file[0].name +" is not a valid image file.");
                        dvPreview.html("");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuUpload" runat="server" multiple="multiple" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="Upload" />
<hr />
<div id="dvPreview">
</div>
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Text.aspx.vb

Place the following code under your upload button.

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To Request.Files.Count - 1
        Dim postedFile As HttpPostedFile = Request.Files(i)
        Dim ext As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName)
        Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim getYear As String = (((((now.ToString("hh") & "") + now.ToString("mm") & "") + now.ToString("ss") & "") + now.ToString("mm") & "") + now.ToString("dd") & "") + now.ToString("yyyy") + now.ToString("fff") + ""
        Dim testName As String = getYear + ext


        If postedFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
            Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)
            postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & fileName) ' Single file either way
            'postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & testName) ' Duplicate file CodeFile and no Namespace
        End If
    Next
```

==Update==
OK, so it was the

```
Dim getYear As String
```

The last part of it was causing the issue.

```
now.ToString("fff")
```

Also happens with a GUID as well.

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

I even tried a random file name for kicks, and it duplicated the files.

```
Path.GetRandomFileName()
```

Though it had nothing to do with the CodeFile, there is still the scratching of the head part of WHY does it duplicate the files with the milliseconds added to it?
If you use the example code I provided and test it, you will see that the Random getYear will work with CodeBehind but not with CodeFile.
So, something is going on with CodeFile that causes this bizarre behavior.

Thanks for any assistance on this issue.
Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I VERY but VERY much doubt changing the use of codepage, and code file will effect the outcome here.

the issue is really quite simple:

You allow a user to up-load mutliple files. But, your 2nd code snip does NOT use the file name, and in fact uses a file name based on the time stamp.

You do realize that if user selects 5 files, then in 99% of cases, the file name (based just on time) will OFTEN and NEAR ALWAYS result in say all 5 files being given the same name.

Remember, when a user selects say 5 files, and then hits submit. The files are not really up-loaded separate, but ALL WILL be part of the submit button (the post-back).

So, AFTER ALL the files are up-loaded, then your code loop runs. and it is in most cases going to run VERY fast - less then 1 second. As a result, all 5 files will be given the same file name.

It is possible that you using a computer found in a dumpster, and it runs slow, so slow that somehow the time to run that loop to save (write) each file takes more then one second.

And remember, you as a general rule would not mess with using codefile vs codebehind.

But, without question, using codebehind probably will at least the first time run MUCH faster. If you use codefile, then the source code is saved and is part of the web page, and is compiled by IIS (internet server).

However, if you use cdebehind, then the code is pre-compiled. This thus suggests perhaps that on first page load when using codefile,  the code runs VERY slow the first time - it has to be compiled on the fly, and this might buy you some extra time, enough that the additional file names increased by one second.

However, with codebehind, then this is NOT likly to occur (in other words, the code will run faster, and ALMOST FOR SURE, that if you up-loaded 5 files, they ALL WILL get the same name if you base the file name on JUST time, and don't for example add say the file name or some other part to distinguish the file names your code generates.

Obviously, your first code snip always works, since you using the file name from the up-load.

The 2nd example? If the computer runs fast, then you almost for sure wind up over writing the set of files with the same time - since that code will run rather fast.

And you should not mess with the codebehind vs codefile settings.

codebehind:

This assumes you are using an asp.net web application. This means that you compile the web site and code BEFORE deployment, and your source code files (code behind) are NOT up-loaded to the server.

CodeFile

This assumes you are NOT using a sp.net application, but are using what is called a asp.net web site. This means that you can deploy one simple page, and not have to re-deploy the whole site (like you do with web applications). This certainly can be easier to maintain a web site, but a web site application also has some advantages, and this is in the area of refencing other code libraries etc. You also tend to require MORE control over the web server, and a web site can easy be published as as sub site, where as in most cases the asp.net web applcation is going to be the root of your site, and the configuration applies to the whole server - not several sub sites.

Anyway, wondering off topic here.

It looks like using the time stamp for the file name is a bad idea, and that loop will surely OFTEN run in less then one second, and that will result in all files having the same file name. You either need to introduce the part of the file name, or even consider a file.Exists(strFile), and maybe then increment the time by 5 seconds or some such if the file already exists (for the file name to be used).

As noted, if you are using codefile, and it seemed to work, it likly due to the code running oh so much slower. However, if you run that page, or do the test multiple times, that page will when loaded, and compiled by IIS will start to run faster, and you then start to see the same file names generated based on using time.

For code behind, then it is pre-compiled, and thus the chance of the time changing from one file save to the next will increase, and once again, file based on time stamp will no doubt start to over write each other in that loop.

## Edit: two examples web site, and web site application

Ok, so lets create two projects. We use the time stamp example in both.

so, lets create a web site (not a web site application).

So, this one:

[image]

so, to be 100% clear, we do NOT open this as a project.
Thus we ALWAYS will open this project with open web site option from VS.

so, to open + develop, we use open web site, and NOT open application.

Eg this:

[image]

And then this to open:

[image]

And of course, it ALWAYS dangerous to mess around with the code file and page settings (that first header in the markup).

So, we add a new page - MyTest (and we MOST certainly let VS create this page for us, right????).

So, we now cut + paste in your markup:

And we now have this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MyTest.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=fuUpload]").change(function () {
            if (typeof (FileReader) !="undefined") {
                var dvPreview = $("#dvPreview");
                dvPreview.html("");
                var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
                $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                    var file = $(this);
                    if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                        var reader =new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            var img = $("<img />");
                            img.attr("style","height:100px;width: 100px");
                            img.attr("src", e.target.result);
                            dvPreview.append(img);
                        }
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
                    }else {
                        alert(file[0].name +" is not a valid image file.");
                        dvPreview.html("");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="fuUpload" runat="server" multiple="multiple" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" Text="Upload" runat="server" OnClick="Upload" />
            <hr />
        <div id="dvPreview">
        </div>


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I did not mess with the page directive, I pasted in your bits in parts.

And for code behind, we have this:

```
Partial Class MyTest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Upload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        For i As Integer = 0 To Request.Files.Count - 1

            Dim postedFile As HttpPostedFile = Request.Files(i)
            Dim ext As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName)
            Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
            Dim getYear As String = (((((now.ToString("hh") & "") + now.ToString("mm") & "") + now.ToString("ss") & "") + now.ToString("mm") & "") + now.ToString("dd") & "") + now.ToString("yyyy") + now.ToString("fff") + ""
            Dim testName As String = getYear + ext


            If postedFile.ContentLength > 0 Then
                Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)
                'postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & fileName) ' Single file either way
                postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") & testName) ' Duplicate file CodeFile and no Namespace
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

I added a folder to the project Uploads.

I only get one file. That web site saved as a zip file is here:

Now, if you want to mess around, and try changing CodeFile settings, then be my guest - but I would NOT risk doing as such, since a web site assumes that IIS will compile that code.

Ok, now lets do this with a asp.net web site project. This one:

[image]

And again, now we do NOT use open web site, but will use open project when you want to work on this application.

so, link to first example - zipped web site (not app), open as web site.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avrwal_LV4qxhpxvZPRHjzs6JES-LQ?e=HQvgp9

And link to 2nd example - zipped web site applcation. Open the project file.

(so you open with open project - choose the sln file).

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avrwal_LV4qxhpxuJis0Pwwf4jwxxg?e=WUnx8m

Both of these work with the time stamp file example. Neither triggers two files.

Now, at this point, you are free as a bird to start mucking around with the page heading directive - but I been do this for LONG time, and have NEVER messed with that page directive header. I might have touch one when importing a web page from another project.

HOWEVER, you want to let asp.net and the designers create the page heading directive. And I VERY much doubt you can mess with a flip between CodeFile, and codebehind, since that setting is used for TWO VERY different types of projects and a different deployment model.

## Edit4: the problem

Remember, I suggested this:

*Try changing name of click event. Say test_click. Better yet, remove existing name and use ctrl- space to pop the choice to create new event. It will become ctrl name+ _click, and see if that prevents the double run the code. (Thus move code to new event name)stub*

Note carefully in above - I said MOVE the code to a new event stub behind.

When you place a button on a form, you HAVE TWO choices here. You can EITHER double click on the button - and then code behind wires up a Handles event.

OR YOU CAN put the event name in the markup, and YOU WILL NOT be using, nor get a handles event.

In above suggestion, I stated to remove the default click you have, erase it, and then hit ctrl-space. You get this:

[image]

So, that will create a NEW event stub in code behind. And NOTE very, but very carefully I stated this:

*Thus move code to new event name)stub*

In other words, we remove the other stub.

So, the reason (of couse!!!) is that a static file name works, is that the code WAS running two times, but since the name is the same, you get one file - the same file.

If you use milliseconds, and HAVE TWO events wired up to the one button, then the code stub fires two times. (and you get two files as a result)

And HOW MANY times did I ask this:

quote:

*when you say you get two files, is your sub being called two times? Or does the for/next loop run two times? Which is it?*

and this:

quote:

*but then you not answered the question. Does the code run two times? that code can't create two files unless it runs two time, or is called two times. If you put in a break-point, and debug the code when it runs, what happens? single step that code, and determine if the routine is called two times, or the loop runs two times*

and this:
quote:

*You did not try my break-point suggestion - you need to do that.*

So, when I asked above multiple times - I assume you tested, checked, and REMOVED that from our list of things to check. Skipping a suggestion to test/check try during a trouble shooting session is a VERY bad thing to do. I take that out and off the list once I add that question + suggestion. I have to assume you double checked, and double tested that solution.

So, you did not follow up on my things to try - ignored them.

So, the issue was and is simple. There was two events attached to the button click, the code stub runs two times. And with milisecond file name, then you get two files. With a single file name, it ALSO was running two times, but you saving the file two times.

So, this issue I brough up was ignored.

So, either use the screen cap ctrl-space to create the event stub in markup, OR double click on the button and let the code behind have a handler. (but, you had both active at the same time). (aand of couse then remove the onclick in the markup - you can't have both active).

So, remove the onclick in markup (and remove the code beind stub). Now try the double click to crate the event.

You can add the event EITHER way as per above, but you can't have a handles event (in code behind) AND ALSO a onclick in the markup.

So, do one, or the rother - but not both. So you can have or add onclick in the markup (use ctrl-space) -- create new event, and REMOVE the (or any) old event with the "handles" directive.

Good luck!